# ASP.NET Empty Web Applcation for F#

Tags: asp.net, f#

Does anyone know if there are web templates for F#?  Specifically, the ASP.NET Empty Web Application.  I am looking for VS2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this is not exactly what I need to create a F# Web Applcation - I don't want any C# at all.  I went and added this line to the .fsproj file like this:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

But I get this when I try and load the project:

> error  : Specified method is not supported.

I guess FSharp can't be used for a web application?  How lame is that?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind - found it on the Online Templates under Visual F#.

Thanks